# How to validate three fields so one always has a value

Tags: jquery

I have the following three fields:

**1st Field**:

```
<input class="emailrequerido" name="emailrecomendado1_<?php echo $patrocinado->idpatroc; ?>" id="emailrecomendado1_<?php echo $patrocinado->idpatroc; ?>" placeholder="user@domain.com" type="text" />
```

**2nd Field**:

```
<select name="contactos<?php echo $patrocinado->idpatroc; ?>[]" id="contactos<?php echo $patrocinado->idpatroc; ?>" multiple="3" style="width:49%" class="contactorequerido">
```

**3rd Field**:

```
<select name="grupos<?php echo $patrocinado->idpatroc; ?>[]" id="grupos<?php echo $patrocinado->idpatroc; ?>" multiple="3" style="width:49%" class="gruporequerido">
```

**Submit Field**:

```
<input id="enviarForm" type="submit" class="uk-button uk-float-right" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_PATROCINADOR_SEND_RECOM');?>"/>
```

I need to have always one of the three fields with a value before your allowed to submit.

I have tried the following:

```
 $("#enviarForm").click(function() {
    if($(".emailrequerido").val() == false){
        $('.contactorequerido').attr('required', true);
        $('.gruporequerido').attr('required', true);
    }else if($(".contactorequerido option:selected").val() == false){
        $('.emailrequerido').attr('required',true);
        $('.gruporequerido').attr('required',true);
    }else if($(".gruporequerido option:selected").val() == false){
        $('.emailrequerido').attr('required',true);
        $('.contactorequerido').attr('required',true);
    }

    if($(".emailrequerido").val() == true){
        $('.contactorequerido').removeAttr('required');
        $('.gruporequerido').removeAttr('required');
    }else if($(".contactorequerido option:selected").val() == true){
        $('.emailrequerido').removeAttr('required');
        $('.gruporequerido').removeAttr('required');
    }else if($(".gruporequerido option:selected").val() == true){
        $('.emailrequerido').removeAttr('required');
        $('.contactorequerido').removeAttr('required');
    }
})
```

Comment: Please post the client-side code. That is, the code that is sent to the client **after** being processed by PHP.

Comment: @oGeez I believe that what your asking is not necessary for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Disallow submission here initially ...

$(":input").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
var comboVal = $('.emailrequerido').val()+$('.contactorequerido').val()+$('.gruporequerido').val();
    if(comboVal == 'nullnull'){
      // Don't allow!!! May disable or hide submission button
    } else {
      // Allow :D 
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What if the user only wants to add an email and not select any of the other fields? If only one field has value it should validate

Comment: :input selector covers all, input and select. Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/effone/84suD/

Comment: Do I need to add that under `$("#enviarForm").click(function() {` ?

Comment: Don't think so. Disable submission at document ready. and use the function provided to allow submission.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
$("#enviarForm").click(function() {
    if($('[id^="emailrecomendado1_"]').val() == "" || 
       $('[id^="contactos"]').val() == "" || 
       $('[id^="grupos"]').val() == ""){
      alert('one field required.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them all the same class, for example `req`. Then do:

```
$('#enviarForm').submit(function(){
  return $('.req').filter(function(){return $(this).val();}).length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Sure, it counts how many elements with a class `req` have a value and returns true if it's more than zero.

Answer (score 0):

try this-- might help.. but not sure..

```
$("#enviarForm").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var error=0;
    if($(".emailrequerido").val() == false){
        $('.contactorequerido').attr('required', true);
        $('.gruporequerido').attr('required', true);
        error++;
    }
    if($(".contactorequerido option:selected").val() == false){
        $('.emailrequerido').attr('required',true);
        $('.gruporequerido').attr('required',true);
         error++;
    }
    if($(".gruporequerido option:selected").val() == false){
        $('.emailrequerido').attr('required',true);
        $('.contactorequerido').attr('required',true);
          error++;
    }

    if($(".emailrequerido").val() == true){
        $('.contactorequerido').removeAttr('required');
        $('.gruporequerido').removeAttr('required');
    }
    if($(".contactorequerido option:selected").val() == true){
        $('.emailrequerido').removeAttr('required');
        $('.gruporequerido').removeAttr('required');
    }
    if($(".gruporequerido option:selected").val() == true){
        $('.emailrequerido').removeAttr('required');
        $('.contactorequerido').removeAttr('required');
    }
    if(error==0){
        ("#formid").submit();
    }
});
```